# Tomcat Run Php through Php/ Java Bridge

Tags: php, tomcat, php-java-bridge

im working with tomcat and im tryng to run php thorugh tomcat. fot that i downloaded a sample JavaBridge.war file and pasted it into webapps folder of tomcat. but when i start the tomcat server it says

> 'he-tomcat-10.1.10\webapps\JavaBridge.war] 05-Jul-2023 20:19:09.066
> INFO [main] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one
> JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging
> for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no
> TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can
> improve startup time and JSP compilation time. 05-Jul-2023
> 20:19:09.118 SEVERE [main]
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal One or more
> listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the
> appropriate container log file 05-Jul-2023 20:19:09.625 WARNING [main]
> org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGeneratorBase.createSecureRandom
> Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using
> [SHA1PRNG] took [504] milliseconds. 05-Jul-2023 20:19:09.626 SEVERE
> [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Context
> [/JavaBridge] startup failed due to previous errors'

and when i hit the 'http://localhost:8080/JavaBridge/' i get the output in image.

i tried many possible solutions, but no one worked

Comment: Where did you get this `war` file from?

Comment: i downloaded it from here https://php-java-bridge.sourceforge.net/pjb/installation.php

Comment: So is Java 1.4 and PHP 5 acceptable?  This is a horrible hack that is documented to only support Tomcat 6 from 2007.  You can't use this 16 years later.  It also requires Apache (1.x) or IIS and you don't mention that.  You need to rethink your solution as no one has used this in a decade plus.

Comment: i think that was issue with tomcat version, i was using tomcat10, i changed it to tomcat-9.0.76 and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

My issue is resolved. I was using `tomcat10`, I changed it to `tomcat9` and it worked.